NHibernate mapping by XML: How to map IDictionary?
This is a near-cloned question of NHibernate mapping by code: How to map IDictionary?
How can I map these Entities using NHibernate XML file:
public class Foo
{
    public virtual IDictionary<int, Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}


Most answers are in regards to mapping-by-code or Fluent NHibernate, I would appreciate help on how to do it using xml mapping files.
Closest thing I found is the official Collection Mapping Documentation but it is unclear on what to do for IDictionary collections.

Out of curiosity, why are you using the instance as the dictionary's key? I'm not sure NH is going to be able to help you there. If you look at the <map-key> element and how it's used, there's an example here, its type can be specified but its value is that of an underlying database column or formula.

Hi @DavidOsborne thank you for pointing this out. I completely missed that. I modified the key and value types of the dictionary to be aligned to what i am looking for
